# Simple trie class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, trie

I would be very grateful to get some thoughts on this toy-implementation of a trie that I wrote to practice my C++.

Some questions I have:

- Is my `create` member function idiomatic? What's the standard way avoid duplicated copy in the copy-constructor and assignment operator?
- Is there a way that I could avoid using the virtual function `get_word`? It seems safer to use a virtual function (to avoid accessing undefined memory), but it I don't see why I shouldn't be able to lookup the address where `this->word` could reside.

General tips are appreciated, not just answers to these questions.

Thanks!

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class TrieNode {
public:
    std::unordered_map<char, TrieNode*> children;

    TrieNode() {}
    TrieNode(TrieNode const& trie_node) { create(trie_node); };
    TrieNode& operator=(TrieNode const& rhs) {
        if (&rhs != this) {
            children.clear();
            create(rhs);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    virtual ~TrieNode() {
        for (auto const& it: children) {
            delete it.second;
        }
    }
    void create(TrieNode const&);
    virtual std::string const& get_word() const { throw std::domain_error("get_word() called on non-terminal node."); };

};

class TerminalTrieNode: public TrieNode {
// terminal nodes represent full words
// they are pointed to by edges with key '\0'
public:
    std::string word;
    std::string const& get_word() const {return word;}
    TerminalTrieNode(std::string word): word(word) {}
    TerminalTrieNode(TrieNode const* terminal_trie_node) {
        create(*terminal_trie_node);
        word = terminal_trie_node->get_word();
    }
};

void TrieNode::create(TrieNode const& trie_node) {
    for (auto const& it: trie_node.children) {
        if (it.first != '\0')
            children[it.first] = new TrieNode(*it.second);
        else
            children[it.first] = new TerminalTrieNode(it.second);
    }
}

class Trie {
private:
    TrieNode root;
    void apply_all(TrieNode const* node, void (function(std::string const&))) const {
        // helper function for prefix_apply
        // applies the given function to every word in the trie below the given word
        auto it = node->children.find('\0');
        if (it != node->children.end()) {
            function(it->second->get_word());
        }
        for (auto const& c_it: node->children)
            apply_all(c_it.second, function);
    }
public:
    void insert(std::string const& word) {
        // add a new word to the trie
        TrieNode* node = &root;
        for (char const c: word) {
            if (!node->children[c])
                node->children[c] = new TrieNode();
            node = node->children[c];
        }
        //mark as a terminal node
        node->children['\0'] = new TerminalTrieNode(word);
    }

    bool contains(std::string const& word) const{
        // set-membership test
        TrieNode const* node = &root;
        for (char const c: word) {
            auto it = node->children.find(c);
            if (it == node->children.end()) return false;
            node = it->second;
        }
        return node->children.find('\0') != node->children.end();
    }

    void prefix_apply(std::string const& prefix, void (function(std::string const&))) const {
        // Apply the given function to every word in the trie that has the given prefix
        TrieNode const* node = &root;
        for (char const c: prefix) {
            auto it = node->children.find(c);
            if (it == node->children.end()) return;
            node = it->second;
        }
        apply_all(node, function);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Trie trie;
    trie.insert("apple");
    trie.insert("app");
    trie.insert("apl");
    trie.insert("back");
    trie.insert("appl");
    Trie new_trie = trie;
    new_trie.prefix_apply("app", [](std::string const& s) {std::cout << s << '\n';});
}
```

Comment: To answer the second question: `static_cast<TerminalTrieNode*>(_)->word` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Design

I don't think that `TerminalTrieNode` is that good of an idea, for multiple reasons:

- You effectively cannot insert byte-strings that contain the `char` value `'\0'`. While this isn't likely to come up in purely ASCII based applications, it might e.g. for variants of unicode or handling of raw byte strings.
- Having to use pointers in `TrieNode::children` (due to inheritance) means <s>doubling</s> increasing the amount of pointer dereferences: One for the actual pointer, and at least one hidden in the `std::unordered_map`. This makes all operations slower due to cache misses.
- The whole `get_word` "hack" smells (as you noticed).

Also, it would be nice to retrieve information about which path a node is on.

Ideally, I'd like something along these lines:

```
class TrieNode {
    // Note: store TrieNode by value!
    std::unordered_map<char, TrieNode> children;

    // simple indicator if this is a leaf node (end of a word)
    bool is_leaf_node;

    // A reference to the path so far
    // Note: if memory usage gets too big, this could be replaced by a std::string_view
    // and storing the leaf strings in a dedicated pool. Non-leaf nodes would only refer to
    // a part of the stored string.
    std::string path;

public:
    TrieNode(std::string);
    std::string_view word() const;
    void make_leaf();
    bool is_leaf() const;
};
```

> Sadly, this won't compile, as `std::unordered_map` doesn't support incomplete types (`TrieNode` is incomplete at the declaration of `TrieNode::children`). One easy solution would be using another hash map type that supports incomplete types, e.g. `boost::unordered_map`.
>
> But: This solution sidesteps a lot (if not all) of the problems mentioned in @JVApen's answer.

## Other issues

`Trie::prefix_apply` only takes non-member functions, i.e. no function objects (like capturing lambdas or instance of classes with overloaded `operator(std::string const&)`) or possibly member functions (including the corresponding object). This can be fixed in two ways:

1. Take a `std::function<void(std::string const&)>` as parameter. This supports all of the above, but might incur a heap allocation upon construction.
2. Template it on a `Callable&&` which gets deduced for the passed function. This doesn't incur a heap allocation, but it also doesn't support the (admittedly rare case) usage of pointer to member functions. It also might cause some binary bloat, as a new function is generated for each instantiation (though they might provide more optimization opportunities, e.g. inlining).

> A different design choice would be providing an iterator interface, though implementation of that is a bit more work. The advantage of that would be better compatibility with standard algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this code, I have several remarks, let me start with your questions:

## Is my create member function idiomatic?

No, I barely see it. Mostly because it doesn't add value. Either classes are small enough so it doesn't matter, or copy/assign ain't supported, or it can be defaulted.

In this case, it looks better to have a virtual method `clone` on the nose or make the structure templated (preferred by me).

## Is there a way that I could avoid using the virtual function get_word?

In general I would make the node type would be a template argument, yes. Otherwise, you could cast (similar to CRTP), however that requires knowledge of the available types.
For this specific case, I realize this ain't possible, however, it does make sense having only one node.

## Ownership

You have some memory leaks in your code. I suggest to use a simple rule of thumb: always use unique_ptr instead of new/delete. Or when possible, just store by value in the map.

## Relevance of member functions

`prefix_apply` is a very good example of a function that should be a free function. You make a copy and adapt the whole structure. Why not build up a new map?

At the same time, it is very specific, so you could replace it by the visitor pattern.

## Rule of five

Applying the rule of five allows you to move instead of copying. Most of the time, I even write move operations with the copy variant deleted.

## Public members

Just don't, this is very hard to maintain. Especially when you encounter a specific implementation is buggy.

## Purpose and performance

It looks like you are trying to make an ever growing string pool in which you want to share strings. How about using `std::unordered_set` or just a vector on which to unique/erase.
Both variants will be more memory efficient and most like more performant.

Comment: A `trie` is a specific data structure, used to hold an associative array.  There's a specific tag for it on [SO].  It's common to spell out "five" in "Rule of Five" and not use the digit.

Comment: I stand corrected, let me remove

Comment: Thanks for your response!
Are there really memory leaks? Doesn't `~TrieNode()` recursively delete all of the nodes children before deleting itself?

Comment: Operator= doesn't delete the nodes

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I was thinking that clear would call the destructors, but obviously it doesn't since its values are pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated version that I made with the help of the answers JVApen and hoffmale posted.

Instead of storing the full string in terminal Trie nodes (this can actually increase the space complexity e.g. for the case of a unary tree), I modified `prefix_apply` to generate this strings as needed. This also lets us do away with the inheritance.

`unique_ptr` can take care of all the memory management.

I added an erase member function.

Definitely a big improvement! Thanks for the help!

```
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream> // for example usage


struct TrieNode {
    // unique_ptr + trees are a great match since every vertex has a unique parent
    std::map<char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode>> children;
};

class Trie {
private:
    TrieNode root;

    TrieNode const* find(std::string const& w) const  {
        // Return a pointer to the TrieNode for the last character in w, or nullptr if it doesn't exist.
        TrieNode const* node = &root;
        for (char const c: w) {
            auto const it = node->children.find(c);
            if (it != node->children.end()) {
                node = it->second.get();
            } else return nullptr;
        }
        return node;
    }

    template<typename StringFunction>
    void prefix_apply_helper(TrieNode const* node, std::string& w, StringFunction& f) const{
        // Recursively apply f to all strings at or beneath node in the Trie.
        // w should be the (possibly incomplete) word represented by node.
        if (node->children.find('\0') != node->children.end())
            f(w);
        for (auto const& cw: node->children) {
            if (cw.first != '\0') {
                w.push_back(cw.first);
                prefix_apply_helper(cw.second.get(), w, f);
                w.pop_back();
            }
        }
    }
public:
    void insert(std::string const& w) {
        // Insert a word into the Trie.
        TrieNode* node = & root;
        for (char const c: w) {
            auto const it = node->children.find(c);
            if (it != node->children.end()) {
                node = it->second.get();
            } else {
                auto* new_node = new TrieNode();
                node->children[c] = std::unique_ptr<TrieNode>(new_node);
                node = new_node;
            }
        }
        node->children['\0'];
    }

    bool contains(std::string const& w) const {
        // Check if the Trie contains the word
        auto const* node = find(w);
        if (node)
            return node->children.find('\0') != node->children.end();
        else return false;
    }

    void erase(std::string const& w) {
        // Remove the word from the Trie.
        TrieNode* node = &root;
        bool one_child_chain = false;
        TrieNode* one_child_chain_start = nullptr;
        char one_child_chain_first = '\0';

        for (char const c: w) {
            auto const it = node->children.find(c);
            if (it != node->children.end()) {
                if (!one_child_chain && it->second->children.size() == 1) {
                    one_child_chain = true;
                    one_child_chain_start = node;
                    one_child_chain_first = c;
                } else if (it->second->children.size() != 1) {
                    one_child_chain = false;
                }
                node = it->second.get();
            } else return;
        }
        node->children.erase('\0');
        if (one_child_chain)
            one_child_chain_start->children.erase(one_child_chain_first);

    }

    template<typename StringFunction>
    void prefix_apply(std::string prefix, StringFunction& f) const {
        // Apply f to every word in the Trie that has the given prefix
        auto const* node = find(prefix);
        if (node)
            prefix_apply_helper(node, prefix, f);
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Trie t;
    t.insert("apple");
    t.insert("app");
    t.insert("appalachians");
    t.insert("banana");
    t.erase("appalachians");
    t.insert("appalled");
    t.prefix_apply("app", [](std::string const& w) { std::cout << w << '\n'; });
}
```